# Django django-admin.py import problem (enviroment_variable problem) on Centos

Tags: python, django, configuration, import

I have try to install Django and Python on my brand new dedicated server. 
I made it upto a certain point and I can run `django-admin.py startproject mysite` and it works well. (I have add the path to django-admin.py to .bash_profile).

However, when I try to run `django-admin.py syncdb` it gives me error like

```
File "/opt/python2.7.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 40, in _setup
raise ImportError("Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable %s is undefined." % ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE)
```

I try to set env var such that

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=settings
or
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings
```

but after that it gives error like

```
File "/opt/python2.7.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 92, in __init__
raise ImportError("Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e))
ImportError: Could not import settings 'mysite.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named mysite.settings
```

Could you figure out what is the problem in here and how can I overcome ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although this doesn't answer your question directly, it is an alternative solution.
You should be able to use the command

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

within the main directory of your project

Comment: It's not an alternative solution, it is *the* solution. You should never try and run `django-admin.py` inside a project, that's what `manage.py` is for.

Comment: I was looking at `django-admin.py help` and trying to use the `--settings=SETTINGS` option, but nothing I tried worked... still was getting errors about settings not being on sys.path.  manage.py ftw